# Adaptive Rendering with ASP.Net MVC4

Tags: mobile, asp.net-mvc-4, rendering

Coming through a Google Chrome browser emulator, my website is formatted correctly for the iPhone5. Note that this was done not through Visual Studio, but by simply going to the site www.yeagertech.com with the Chrome browser.

The credentials to LogOn in the upper right is:
username: stageadmin
email address: wsyeager36@msn.com
password: 1234567

When I try to go to the site directly from the iPhone5 itself it's still formatted like a desktop browser. The same happens for an Android phone and a Windows phone when I view the site directly through the phones themselves and not an emulator.

Does anybody have any ideas what else I need to do to get the formatting correct?

In my Global.asax file, I have the following which is all I should need:

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("windowsphone")
            {
                ContextCondition = (context => context.GetOverriddenUserAgent().IndexOf
                    ("windowsphone", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
            });

            DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("iPhone")
            {
                ContextCondition = (context => context.GetOverriddenUserAgent().IndexOf
                    ("iPhone", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
            });

            DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("Android")
            {
                ContextCondition = (context => context.GetOverriddenUserAgent().IndexOf
                    ("Android", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
            });

            DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("iPad")
            {
                ContextCondition = (context => context.GetOverriddenUserAgent().IndexOf
                    ("iPad", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
            });

            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone 5 has increased the screen resolution to 1,136 x 640 px at the same 326 pixels per inch (ppi) as previous Retina Devices. The iPhone automatically scales the viewport to fit 980 px so it works well with most webpages without any changes. If you’d like to specifically target the default screen size of the iPhone for a mobile site you can add the following metatag to the head in you layout: `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">`  and see the [Safari Viewport Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html)

You can duplicate what happens on an Android with the Opera Mobile Emulator - http://www.opera.com/developer/tools/mobile/.  Also, put some breakpoints in Global.asax.cs and make sure you are getting the expected result from your User Agent.

I'd also recommend putting some debugging code in each of your device unique views to make sure that the expected view is being rendered for the each device.

You need to fix your JS errors before looking at rendering.  You are loading jquery libraries before JQuery is loaded.  Fix that first.  Then, note that the iPhone 5 renders @ 640px x 1136px on a 4in screen.  A Galaxy S-III renders 720px wide on a little larger screen - which cause issues for lots of developers.  For a quickstart, I'd recommend going back to the default desktop & mobile DisplayModes and then take a look at Bootstrap - http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html - Bootstrap is a great quickstart for responsive design.

Comment: Shouldn't I just have what I just edited in my original post from my global.asax file? according to everything I've read, this should take care of the proper rendering.

Comment: do you have a _layout.iPhone.cshtml or index.iPhone.cshtml?  The DisplayModeProvider says - if the UserAgent contains "iPhone" then use _layout.iPhone.cshtml & index.iPhone.cshtml to render the view.  See explanation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs11trainingcourse_aspnetmvc4_topic4.aspx

Comment: NOTE - that there are two items already in DisplayModeProvider: an empty string for the default desktop version, and "mobile"

Comment: Yes, for each type of phone I have in my global.asax file, I have a similiar masterpage with the naming convention you mentioned.

Comment: Like I mentioned, if you view the website with Chrome and its built in emulator, it renders fine. When I actually go to the website on a mobile phone, it doesn't render properly.

Comment: What do you mean by "Chrome and its built in emulator?"  are you using a plug-in?  Is the emulator sending the expected User Agent?

Comment: In Chrome, if you go to Tools | Developer Tools, in the lower right you will see a settings tab. click on the Overrides tab, click user agent and select how you want the page rendered specific to a device.

Comment: add an H1 with "iPhone" in your index.iPhone.cshtml - fix your javascript errors and note the edits in the answer above.